# How to force an ally's units off my ship

Tags: freeciv

Sometimes, an allied nation will load their units onto one of my ships. This could disrupt my plans, as their units take up space that I would rather use to transport my own units. Short of cancelling the alliance, is there a way to force an allied player's units off my ship?